# Unique name constraint accross siblings in a closure tree

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, unique-constraint, transitive-closure-table

I'm wondering how to enforce a unique constraint for the names of sibling nodes when using a [closure table](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/14/moving-subtrees-in-closure-table/) in MySQL to model a hierarchy.

This is my schema:

```sql
create table spaces (
  id int not null, 
  name varchar(50) not null,
  parent int not null,
  primary key (id),
  foreign key (parent) references spaces(id),
  unique key (name, parent)
)

create table space_paths (
  ancestor int not null,
  descendant int not null,
  depth int not null,
  primary key (ancestor, descendant),
  foreign key (ancestor) references spaces(id),
  foreign key (descendant) references spaces(id)
)
```

With this schema I'm using a unique constraint on the `spaces` table to verify that no sibling has the same name.

The downside of this approach is that it denormalizes the hierarchy metadata encapsulated in the `space_paths` table. The implication is that I would need to manually manage the consistency of `parent` field in the `spaces` table with the paths in the `space_paths` table.

Is there a way I could redesign the schema to have the database enforce a unique name constraint across siblings without having to denormalize?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the cause of denormalization? Or how you imagine ideally the space_paths table structure would be?

Comment: The denormalization I'm referring to is the fact that the parent-child relationship information that the `space_paths` table is responsible for is duplicated by the `unique key (name, parent)` constraint. Theoretically, if somebody accessed the table directly, or via a bug in the app, you could update the `parent` column in the `spaces` table to refer to a different parent than the one managed in the `space_paths` table. So whilst the benefits of the closure tree approach outweigh the costs, I was wondering if there was another way to enforce sibling uniqueness to avoid this duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Using a closure table isn't really a relevant part of your problem here—you just want a `UNIQUE KEY` on `parent, name`, and that's what it seems like you've already got defined, so you should be good.

One thing that may be causing you grief is that you have a `NOT NULL` constraint on the `parent` column. How are you going to support "root" nodes? You could make root nodes use a parent value equal to their ID column, but that will require a self-assigned primary key (AFAIK you can't reference the autoincrement value in an insert statement):

```sql
INSERT INTO spaces(id, name, parent) values (0, 'root', 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can reduce the issue down to it just being a case of wanting to apply a unique key on two columns. The motivation stems from the design decision to manage a tree using the closure table approach. In my particular application, I also need to enforce uniqueness across siblings under any given node. This is a requirement is not fulfilled by the standard closure table mechanism. In the end, I ended up using the unique and not null constraints, since these are nice things that the DB does for you. Also, my app already used a snowflake, so auto-incrementing keys were not an issue.